# Unprivileged user sends commands to init (systemd), how could he get root?

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation

Yes, it would definitely be pretty bad.  I'm just searching for heavier arguments about why the design of `systemd` is the way it is (security wise).

This is a follow up on an [interesting question on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310146/how-do-i-skip-the-90s-timeout-in-systemd/310156?noredirect=1#comment545824_310156).  The question discusses that at user logout `systemd` is waiting (the default, configurable) 90 seconds for a disk to become available, the user knows that the disk is not there and wants to skip that wait.  I argue that the only option is to configure `systemd` to use a shorter delay.  This is because allowing an unprivileged user to give instructions (let's say through an interrupt signal) to `systemd` would be an issue.

For example: an unprivileged user that can send signals to `systemd` could wait for an administrator to restart SELinux and provoke a failure during its startup.  That is the example I got from the top of my head.

Now, let's assume that someone actually writes a wrapper for user logout that will run under `setuid`, this will be done for a "easy of use" of `systemd` (e.g. send an interrupt that will disable timeout before a SIGKILL is sent to a process that did not terminate with SIGTERM).  This isn't particularly hard to write, you can simply create a script and add it to the display manager configuration (`lighdm` has `session-cleanup-script=`, `gdm` has `PostSession` scripts, or even a plain `.bash_logout` for headless machines).  The wrapper will allow for a communication with the SIGNAL interface of `systemd`, which is in `man systemd` under the `SIGNALS` section.

To focus the question let's look on privilege escalation.  i.e. if we have an attacker that managed to get access to an unprivileged user account and can now give commands to `systemd` through that wrapper, how could he escalate privileges into a `root` account?

Comment: I don' think that this question makes sense. A user is unable to send signals to systemd because the user does not have the permissions (OS feature). If the user would be able to send signals to systemd by using some helper then systemd would have been designed differently regarding handling of signals. So in any case you would argue about something which does not reflect the reality at all.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I know, I'm arguing about a rather hypothetical situation.  Yet it is possible for example to build a setiud program that will perform the signaling.  And I would not be surprised that someone would build such thing, for the purpose of "easy of use" of the system.

Comment: Maybe you should not restrict your question to signals then but to "non-privileged user gives systemd instructions" because that seems to be your main concern. Signals are just one of many ways for IPC and in most cases not a good one (i.e. sets only flag, no idea what/who caused the signal...) . But unless you be more specific what kind of actions you are concerned about the question would probably be too broad.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Good point, I changed it to include all IPC but also reduced the scope to privilege escalation.

Comment: That a user is communicating with or directly executing a privileged process is actually very common (passwd change, login, sudo, ping...) and by itself is no new attack surface. But usually the privileged  programs are  designed to explicitly allow this. I think what you want to ask is how bad it would be if somebody writes a wrapper to allow a non-privileged user use interfaces which are only intended for privileged users (i.e. signals). But even then I think the question is too broad as long as you don't restrict it to specific actions you think somebody would want to wrap this way.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I revamped it but slightly differently.  I describe the wrapper as a setuid script that runs on session logout (a thing that most display manager can handle) or shell logout.  I also trimmed down the available systemd interface.

Comment: I agree the question is very signal-centric. Anything like this would probably be accomplished with dbus.

Comment: @GnP - Hmm... you make me curious now.  I never used DBUS for anything, how would you use DBUS to interact with systemd on user logout?  (e.g. what would you place on DBUS to make a systemd service give up early and force SIGKILL a process).  I'm clueless on DBUS.